Bayesian Statistics vs. Frequentist Statistics for Uninformative Uniform Priors
I have a really basic question about Bayesian statistics.
Lets say you have an uninformative prior that you know comes from a uniform distribution. Is there any benefit to using a Bayesian approach versus using the MLE approach in Frequentist statistics? Would you not get similar results?

It depends on what you mean by "having" a prior.  When a specific prior is justified by more than some philosophical argument about "all probability is subjective," then most people would have no problem exploiting it.  Whether that's a benefit depends on how you use it.  Maybe you could clarify your meaning?

Yes, but it mostly depends on what kind of action you’re going to take from the model.

There are no uninformative priors.

Cross-posted.

FWIW, frequentists and Bayesians both put background knowledge into their modelling. They do it by different methods, but it leads to the same thing.

@whuber I am pretty new to Bayesian statistics, so I'll probably use a lot of wrong terminology. Essentially, what I am trying to do is run a program in R using a Beta prior distribution to estimate a theta value I randomly generate using a uniform distribution. I used an alpha and beta of 1, but when I ran the program, I noticed I was getting values really similar to an MLE approach, so I was curious as to if there is any reason at all to even use a Bayesian model for such a problem? Sorry if this does not answer your question.

@Galen I understand that, but wouldn't Bayesian models do much better at small sample sizes?

@StrangerX The posterior will tend to be more dependent on the prior when sample sizes are smaller. That can lead to either better or worse results when compared to some "ground truth".

@Galen So for small sample sizes, it will be better or worse depending on what prior is chosen? If so, how would you choose a prior with very little information? I am familiar with Jeffrey's prior, the Beta(1,1) prior, and some more, but how would you know what to choose in a circumstance?

@StrangerX I use a combination of information gathering about background knowledge to formulate constraints, the principle of maximum entropy within the given constraints, and prior predictive simulations to sanity check.

Also some of the models I develop are 'not' for accurate inference but for decisions that are robust to risk. As such, I'm not against using priors that err a bit on the side of assuming that implausible bad outcomes have non-tiny probabilities.

I think that you need to think about what type of inference you wish to make. A Bayesian posterior from a uniform prior will be proportional to the likelihood function, but the inference from a posterior is based on probabilities and that from a likelihood function is based on likelihood ratios. They differ in their scope as the former can represent 'belief' in light of evidence and the latter is just the evidence.

I'm not really 'a' Bayesian, but in my opinion a uniform prior is only good to bootstrap (not in the statistical sense) the Bayesian analysis where the data is sufficient to overwhelm any reasonable prior. (In such a case I would prefer to simply use the likelihood function and think about the evidence and statistical model directly.) If you have a small sample then I would strongly advise against the uniform prior as it would often give undue weight to minimal data.

@MichaelLew I advise against a de facto assumption of uniform priors regardless of sample size. Uniform distributions may come up in rare, specialized, or artificial situations, but a uniform distribution is an implausible default because it requires 'perfect' symmetries that are not plausibly realized. Even the rolling/flipping of real dice and coins are not exactly uniform in their outcomes. In practice the PoME does not point me to the PoI.

@Galen I don't offer any direct advice on the issue, and would not suggest any prior as a default. I do not support any mindless application of defaults. Nonetheless, the choice of a uniform prior does not matter if there is enough data. No prior matters if there is enough data, no matter what theoretical objections you might come up with. The space between statistical theory and real-world inference is wide enough that I do not worry about "PoME" or "PoI". It is much more important to understand the types of inference that might be made.

@MichaelLew I find the principle of maximum entropy useful on real inferences.

I suspect it is true that for a fixed non-degenerate prior there exists a random data set sufficiently large for the posterior to become epsilon-close to the likelihood function itself. I expect it is also the case that for a fixed non-degenerate likelihood set there exists a prior such that the posterior is be epsilon-close to the prior. In an extreme case the use of a Dirac delta distribution centered at some parameter value as a prior would a priori select a parameter value via the sifting property.

We agree that mindless defaults are problematic.

@Galen Thanks for that. I don't know exactly what it means to be a "Dirac delta distribution" and would not doubt that one could cleverly choose a stupid prior that behaves badly in your circumstance of theory. However, I do doubt that such a situation would come up in normal practice. And if it did then the stupidity of the prior would be pointed out by an observer.

@MichaelLew A Dirac delta distribution as a prior would mean almost surely sampling a particular parameter value. It is like fixing a parameter to a constant value. Naturally, if you are setting a parameter to an exact value that means you are taking it as a practical certainty. The speed of light is a plausible example of a parameter to hold constant.

A couple of examples of parameters that we can put pretty strong (but not absolutely certain) priors on include the resting mass of an electron and the homeostatic body temperature of a human. You may need these as parameters in a model even though you could be primarily interested in other parameters, or you might only be interested in the posterior predictive distribution rather than any of the parameters per se.

How bizzare to close your question when your question is so much more specific (only uninformative priors) than is the 'duplicate'. I hope you are able to find an answer there
